# Why Blueprint in Python Flask is not working although is seems so easy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Im doing a project. And right now i decided to break it into small parts using blueprint. Acording to the output my variable modapi is no acessible trought app.py. The output is showed in the final of the post.

```
C:.
│   app.py
│   appaux.py
│   db.yaml
│
├───.vscode
│       settings.json
│
├───blue
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───api
│   │   │   forms.py
│   │   │   routes.py
│   │   │   utils.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
```

## app.py

```
from blue import create_app,create_MySQL_connection
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, jsonify

app = create_app()

mysql = create_MySQL_connection(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## blue/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml
from flask_cors import CORS

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(__name__)

    db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
    app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']

    #mysql = MySQL(app)
    CORS(app)

    from blue.api.routes import modapi
    # from blue.site.routes import mod

    # app.register_blueprint(site.routes.mod)
    app.register_blueprint(modapi, url_prefix='/api')

    from blue.api import routes
    app.register_blueprint(routes)

    return app

def create_MySQL_connection(app):
    return MySQL(app)
```

## blue/routes.py

```
from app import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, jsonify

#from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, jsonify
from Flask import Blueprint
#from blue import create_app

from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flask import request, Response
import json
import yaml
from  flask_cors import CORS
from app import mysql
from blue.api.utils import extract_tables
from blue.api.forms import *

# IMPORTES NECESSARIOS PARA A COMPARACAO ATRAVES DE DATASET DOS COMANDOS DE SQL
import sqlparse
import MySQLdb._mysql
import pandas
import datacompy
from mysql.connector import Error


modapi = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@modapi.route('/v1.0/alunos/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def alunos():
   ...
```

C:\Users\joaog\Documents\tryflask\blue__init__.py:10: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in 
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\Users\joaog\Documents\tryflask\blue__init__.py", line 19, in create_app
    from blue.api.routes import modapi
  File "C:\Users\joaog\Documents\tryflask\blue\api\routes.py", line 1, in 
    from app import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, jsonify
  File "C:\Users\joaog\Documents\tryflask\app.py", line 4, in 
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\Users\joaog\Documents\tryflask\blue__init__.py", line 19, in create_app
    from blue.api.routes import modapi

## ImportError: cannot import name 'modapi' from 'blue.api.routes' (C:\Users\joaog\Documents\tryflask\blue\api\routes.py)

Comment: The only question I see here is "Is easy to learn Blueprint in Python Flask?", which is off-topic due to being primarily opinion-based.  What is the actual question you want to ask?

Comment: @jwodder title changed. Why is my question down coted?

Answer (score 0):

i think you're wrong when import routes...

please take a look

blue/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'qqwer%t&'

from blue.api.routes import modapi

app.register_blueprint(modapi, url_prefix='/api')
```

blue/api/routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

modapi = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@modapi.route('/')
def alunos():
    return 'Hello World alunos'
```

it's should be work

Comment: hi, @flakavir first thanks for looking at this bug. Second it is just firmily similar to what i have wrote it does not differ except in app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'something'

Comment: just remove ```from blue.api import routes``` and it's should be work